# Internal HTML Styles Not Applying to Elements? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I would like to use an internal style sheet instead of an external style sheet, but for some reason, the styles are not applying to my HTML?

How can I get my styles to apply to my HTML, without making an external CSS sheet, or using inline styles?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <style type=”text/css”>
        form{
            height: 350px;
            width: 200px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Contact</h1>
    </header>
    <nav></nav>
    <main>
        <h2>Send us feedback</h2>
        <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
            <label for="fName">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First name">
            <label for="lName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last name">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
            <label for="pNumber">Phone number</label>
            <input type="number" name="pNumber" placeholder="Phone number">
            <label for="comments">Comments</label>
            <textarea name="comments" cols="" rows="" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
            <input name="submit" type="submit">
        </form>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `type="text/css"` from your style tag, that is only needed for importing a stylesheet with a `<link />` tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <style>
        form {
            height: 350px;
            width: 200px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Contact</h1>
    </header>
    <nav></nav>
    <main>
        <h2>Send us feedback</h2>
        <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
            <label for="fName">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First name">
            <label for="lName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last name">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
            <label for="pNumber">Phone number</label>
            <input type="number" name="pNumber" placeholder="Phone number">
            <label for="comments">Comments</label>
            <textarea name="comments" cols="" rows="" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
            <input name="submit" type="submit">
        </form>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like for some reason the `type` attribute was making it mad.  Removing it fixes it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <style>
        form{
            height: 350px;
            width: 200px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Contact</h1>
    </header>
    <nav></nav>
    <main>
        <h2>Send us feedback</h2>
        <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
            <label for="fName">First name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fName" placeholder="First name">
            <label for="lName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Last name">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email">
            <label for="pNumber">Phone number</label>
            <input type="number" name="pNumber" placeholder="Phone number">
            <label for="comments">Comments</label>
            <textarea name="comments" cols="" rows="" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
            <input name="submit" type="submit">
        </form>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

For what it's worth [MDN seems to indicate the way you were using the `type` here attribute should be valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#attr-type).  However, they also note:

> **Note:** There is very little reason to include this attribute in modern web documents.

...*and* a bit further down in the [browser compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#browser_compatibility) they mark it "deprecated"-- so seems like it is best omitted.